The current in a Josephson Junction
I have few doubts about the Josephson junction.
So, first of all, the current through the Junction is
$$
I=-2q_p\frac{K}{\hbar}\sqrt{n_1n_2}\sin\Theta
$$
now the books says that if you consider $n_1(t)$ and $n_2(t)$ constant then
$$
I=-2q_p/\hbar K n_0\sin\Theta
$$
and then he derives the formula for the critical current. My first question is this: if $n_1$ and $n_2$ are constant than the current should be zero. Why is this wrong ?
Then, secondly, they say that there are three main effects for a Josephson Junction. The first one, the dc josephson effect, is when you have a non zero current when no voltage is applied, since
$$
I(t)=I_c\sin(\Theta(t))
$$
where
$$
\Theta(t)=\Theta(0)+\frac{2eV}{\hbar}t
$$
But if you have an initial phase difference equals to zero $\Theta(0)=0$ then the current is zero when $V=0$. Does that make sense? the last thing I want to ask is if there is a mathematical model to express the current-voltage characteristic of the Josephson Junction. Because I want to plot it in matlab
